# How do I show that $T$ is invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm really stuck on these linear transformations, so I have $T(x_1,x_2)=(-5x_1+9x_2,4x_1-7x_2)$, and I need to show that $T$ is invertible. So would I pretty much just say that this is the matrix: $$\left[\begin{matrix}-5&9\\4&-7\end{matrix}\right]$$ Then it's inverse must be $\frac{1}{(-5)(-7)-(9)(4)}\left[\begin{matrix}-7&-9\\-4&-5\end{matrix}\right]=\left[\begin{matrix}7&9\\4&5\end{matrix}\right]$. But is that "showing" that $T$ is invertible? I'm also supposed to find a formula for $T^{-1}$. But that's the matrix I just found right?

Comment: To check if a matrix is invertible you just need to prove that the determinant of that matrix is non-zero.Since the determinant of T here is $'-1'$, the matrix is invertible.

Comment: Why doubt what you have shown? If you doubt its validity, just substitute the formula into the expression, and see if it gives you identity.

Comment: In case you are asked to check for the existence of inverse of any matrix,just verify if the determinant is zero or not.You do not need to find the inverse to check if the inverse exists.If determinant is non-zero, then inverse exists !

Comment: Well I guess my main issue was that I wasn't sure whether or not $T(x_1,x_2)=(...)$ was actually the matrix in question or not. I had a feeling it wasn't and that there was an additional step I had to do or something that I missed. These transformations are such a new thing to me.

Comment: The matrix is not *literally* the same as the map $T$, and to identify them with each other requires a choice of basis (if you don't know what this means yet it's probably better to come back to this comment when you do rather than worry about it too much now).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A fast way to check if a matrix is invertible, is to calculate $\det(T)$. If it's equal to $0$, you can't invert $T$, otherwise you can.

To find the general formula to invert a $2 \times 2$ matrix, try inverting one with $a,b,c,d$ as elements.

Spoiler alert : $$
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d 
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}= 
\frac{1}{\det(T)}
\begin{bmatrix}
d & -b \\
-c & a 
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Answer (score 3):

Another way: Note that $T(1,0)=(-5,4)$ and $T(0,1)=(9,-7)$ are linearly independent vectors. Since $T$ maps a two-element basis to two linearly independent vectors, then it is invertible.

Answer (score 2):

you can choose $\{(1,0) ,(0,1)\}$ as a base for your domain space then with attention to linear algebra matrix of $T$ will be $\begin{bmatrix}
-5 &9 \\ 
 4&-7 
\end{bmatrix}$and this a invertible , and any other matrix with other base for domain is ~ to this matrix

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be more in the spirit of the question (it sounds like it is an exercise in a course or book) to write down a linear map $S$ such that $S\circ T$ and $T\circ S$ are both the identity - the matrix you have written down tells you how to do this. Then such an $S$ is $T^{-1}$.

You should also note that there are different matrices that can represent the map $T$, but it is true that checking that any such matrix is invertible amounts to a proof that $T$ is invertible.

This non-uniqueness of matrices also means that I would disagree that the matrix you found is the same thing as "a formula for $T^{-1}$". You should say what the map $T^{-1}$ does to a point $(y_1,y_2)$.

Answer (score 1):

You can also show that $\ker T=\{\vec{0}\}$ by solving linear equations system.